# Pandas Column Split but ignore splitting on specific pattern

Tags: python, pandas, string, split

I have a Pandas Series containing Several strings Patterns as below:

```
stringsToSplit = ['6  Wrap',
                  '1  Salad , 2  Pepsi , 2  Chicken Wrap',
                  '1  Kebab Plate  [1  Bread ]',
                  '1 Beyti Kebab , 1  Chicken Plate  [1  Bread ], 1 Kebab Plate  [1  White Rice ], 1 Tikka Plate  [1  Bread ]',
                  '1 Kebab Plate [1  Bread , 1  Rocca Leaves ], 1  Mountain Dew '
                 ]

s = pd.Series(stringsToSplit)
s

0                                              6  Wrap
1                1  Salad , 2  Pepsi , 2  Chicken Wrap
2                          1  Kebab Plate  [1  Bread ]
3    1 Beyti Kebab , 1  Chicken Plate  [1  Bread ],...
4    1 Kebab Plate [1  Bread , 1  Rocca Leaves ], 1...
dtype: object
```

I would like to split and explode it such that the result would be as follows:

```
0    6  Wrap
1    1  Salad
1    2  Pepsi
1    2  Chicken Wrap
2    1  Kebab Plate [1  Bread ]
3    1 Beyti Keba
3    1  Chicken Plate  [1  Bread ]
3    1 Kebab Plate  [1  White Rice ]
3    1  Tikka Plate  [1  Bread ]
4    1 Kebab Plate [1  Bread , 1  Rocca Leaves ]
4    1  Mountain Dew
```

In order to do the `explode` I need to first `split`. However, if I use `split(',')` that also splits the items between `[]` which I do not want.
I have tried using split using regex but was not able to find the correct pattern.

I would appreciate the support.

Comment: How deeply can the `[]` be nested?

Comment: only once as shown in the example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a regex with a negative lookahead:

```
s.str.split(r'\s*,(?![^\[\]]*\])').explode()
```

output:

```
0                                        6  Wrap
1                                       1  Salad
1                                       2  Pepsi
1                                2  Chicken Wrap
2                    1  Kebab Plate  [1  Bread ]
3                                  1 Beyti Kebab
3                  1  Chicken Plate  [1  Bread ]
3                1 Kebab Plate  [1  White Rice ]
3                     1 Tikka Plate  [1  Bread ]
4    1 Kebab Plate [1  Bread , 1  Rocca Leaves ]
4                               1  Mountain Dew 
dtype: object
```

[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/XFjQn6/1)

Comment: This works perfectly. Thanks. Can you please explain a bit about the regex used?

Comment: See the [link](https://regex101.com/r/XFjQn6/1) at the bottom of my answer ;)

Comment: One question, I see you used [] for the negative lookahead without specifying any characters in between them. I'm not sure how this works.

Comment: the characters are the brackets `]` and `[`

Comment: Ok understood. In simple words "look for a string starts with white spaces followed by comma which is not followed by [ or ]"

Comment: More, "which is not followed by `...]` with ... not being `[`/`]`"